# 3.55 mm jack wiring

Tags: wiring, component-selection

I have two inputs in my circuit which I am feeding using the two jumper wires. I want to use a 3.5 mm female jack in place of those jumper wires. Right now I have this 3.5 mm female jack but i don't know how to wire it. I only need 3 pins i.e input1 , input2 and ground.

This is the jack what i have right now.
[image: jack]
please if anyone can help me out.

[Image source](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10pcs-lot-3-5-headphone-PJ-327A-gold-plated-patch-SMD-Audio-earphones-headphone-socket-PJ327A/32427800323.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a diagram on the data sheet you linked to!

1 is the sleeve (usually ground)
2 is the ring (input 2)
3 is the tip (input 1)
4 and 5 are a switch which is opened when a male jack is inserted.

You can check using a male plug with 3 wires attached to tip, ring, and sleeve, and a multimeter.

[image]

[image]